# Equivalent for Variable with select expression and non-empty content in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have one template (which I cannot change but have to use), that processes the currently selected node, it might look like this (heavily simplified):

```
<xsl:template name="foreignTemplate">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 2.0 I could do something like this to bind "." in that template to an arbitrary variable:

```
<xsl:template match="dummyNode">
    <xsl:variable name="inputString">foobar</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="result" select="$inputString">
        <xsl:call-template name="foreignTemplate" />
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

Given this source document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dummyNode>DUMMY TEXT</dummyNode>
```

applying the above transformation with an XSLT 2.0 processor would evaluate to "foobar".

However, in XSLT 1.0 xsl:variable-Elements cannot have a select attribute and be non-empty at the same time. How can I achieve the same result in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a detailed explanation and complete solutions for both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in XSLT 1.0 xsl:variable-Elements
>   cannot have a select attribute and be
>   non-empty at the same time

First, **the same holds for XSLT 2.0** (and for every instruction that have a @select and allow a sequence constructor in XSLT 2.0)

Second, if you want to change the context node (or context item in XSLT 2.0) before you call a name template, you should do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$here-the-context-you-want"> 
    <xsl:call-template name="foreignTemplate" /> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

> In XSLT 2.0 I could do something like
>   this to bind "." in that template to
>   an arbitrary variable:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="dummyNode"> 
>     <xsl:variable name="inputString">foobar</xsl:variable>
>
>     <xsl:variable name="result" select="$inputString"> 
>         <xsl:call-template name="foreignTemplate" /> 
>     </xsl:variable> 
> </xsl:template>
> ```

**This is not true**.

Both in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 an `<xsl:variable>` can have either a `select` attribute or a body (sequence constructor), but having both at the same time is an error.

**From the XSLT 2.0 [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#variable-values)**: *"[ERR XTSE0620] It is a static error if a variable-binding element has a select attribute and has non-empty content*."

I would recommend the following writing style:

**In XSLT 1.0**: Do not rely on the context node as an implicit parameter. Use explicit parameters:

```
<xsl:template name="foreignTemplate">  
  <xsl:param name="pElement" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$pElement" />       
</xsl:template>
```

and in another template call it like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="foreignTemplate">
 <xsl:with=param name="pElement" select="someExpression"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

**In XSLT 2.0:** Use `<xsl:function>` instead of `<xsl:template>`:

```
<xsl:function name="my:foo" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="pElement" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="string($pElement)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and call it like this as part of any XPath expression:

```
  my:foo(someElement)
```

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation! But, I think you've been too emphatic in rejecting the context node as implicit parameter. Several times is what we do, for example, when we call the identity transformation template.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks, and you're right about the implicit parameter, however I wouldn't recommend this to XSLT novices, because an inadvertent mistake could add too much in their overall confusion with (the new to them area of) XSLT. :)

Comment: thank you! I'm not happy with this either, but as I wrote, I didn't write that template, nor can I change it... :)

Answer (score 0):

To apply the template to a constant string you can use a nodeset that is contained in your stylesheet and access it using the `document` function. With an empty string as parameter the result is the stylesheet document itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423923/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

    <foo:data>foobar</foo:data>

    <xsl:template name="foreignTemplate">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/foo:data">
            <xsl:call-template name="foreignTemplate" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```